# Deserialize JSON

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin

Вот это JSON я разбирал так:

```
{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Noe"}
```

---

```
data class User(val firstName: String = "", val lastName: String = "") {
    class Deserializer : ResponseDeserializable<User> {
        override fun deserialize(content: String) = Gson().fromJson(content, User::class.java)!!

    }
}
```

---

Как разобрать этот? Мне нужно "distance -> value".

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [
      "Пирятинская ул., 33, Абакан, Респ. Хакасия, Россия, 655011"
   ],
   "origin_addresses" : [
      "ул. Гагарина, 48-50, Абакан, Респ. Хакасия, Россия, 655002"
   ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "3,2 км",
                  "value" : 3182
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "8 мин.",
                  "value" : 501
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Старый вариант, но поможет ли он?

```
val resultJson = JSONObject(responseString)
val rows = resultJson.getJSONArray("rows")
val obj = rows.getJSONObject(0)
val elements = obj.getJSONArray("elements")
val element = elements.getJSONObject(0)
val distance = element.getJSONObject("distance")
var value = distance.getInt("value")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем вы усложняете себе жизнь? За то время, которое вы пытаетесь разобраться с этим бедным json-ом, вы могли бы разобраться с Retrofit ([вот пример туториала](https://habrahabr.ru/post/314028/)).

Тогда ваши десериализованные классы выглядели бы так:

```
data class Distance(var text: String, var value: Int)

data class Duration(var text: String, var value: Int)

data class Element(var distance: Distance, var duration: Duration, var status: String)

data class Row(var elements: List<Element>)   

data class Response(var destination_addresses: List<String>, var origin_addresses: List<String>, var rows: List<Row>, var status: String)
```

С чего я это взял? В статье выше примерно описано как это делается на Java, для котлин это будет еще проще: копируете ваш json [вот сюда](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/), и просто делаете из этого дата-классы. Можно скопировать Java-код в котлин файл и подредактировать, но я и руками секунд за 30 справился.

Далее всё будет проще некуда:

```
// ... проводите все нужные действия, переписывать статью сюда я не буду
apiObject.methodName(param_0, param_1).enqueue(object : Callback<Response>) {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<Response>, response: Response<Response>) {   
        // Здесь делаете всё, что вам нужно 
        val resp = response.body()
        val destination_addresses = resp.destination_addresses
        // и так далее
        // я мог немного ошибиться, подправьте сами, но суть такая
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<Response>, t: Throwable) {
            // обрабатываем ошибку
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я только начал с этим разбираться и сложности возникают на каждом этапе. Где-то отвалится библиотека, где-то переменная, где-то не понял суть...и приходится скакать. Где у меня получилось, так это на OkHttp, а вот с переездом на Fuel и data class возникли проблемы. Точнее уже когда делаю десериализацию.

Comment: Я же вам и привел тогда пример на okHttp. Но вы зачем-то в очередной раз всё усложняете :) Если вам нужно постоянно работать с каким-то апи, делать разные запросы с разными параметрами - используйте Retrofit. Если же у вас только один запрос и даже адрес и параметры, с которыми вы делаете запрос, не меняется, тогда можете использовать что-то простое вроде okHttp.

Comment: Сразу постарайтесь оценивать, что вы собираетесь сделать, и лучше немного постараться и разобраться с чем-то качественным (вроде ретрофита) и потом с легкостью делать всё, что вам нужно, - или неделями ковыряться, пытаясь что-то сложное сделать простыми методами

Comment: Стоит задача, чтобы с api google собирать значение посчитанного расстояние по дорогам. Только лишь значение одного поля.

Comment: Значит, вполне логично что запрос будет не один и тот же у вас постоянно - тогда разбирайтесь с ретрофитом, мой вам совет.